# NDEF in P2P (LLCP)

Tags: nfc, ndef, nfc-p2p

I am trying to understand a communication beetween two NFC phones where I have exchanged a contact.

So there is what I got:

```
B2 4D DD D5 07 03 13 20 00 10 02 00 00 00 D0 D2 0C C1 74 65 78 74 2F 78 2D 76 43 61 72 64 42 45 47 49 4E 3A 56 43 41 52 44 0D 0A 56 45 52 53 49 4F 4E 3A 32 2E 31
```

B24D is SyncCode, DD is LEN, D5 is CMD0, 07 is CMD1 (it's a DEP_RES) and 03 is PFB.
That's OK.

So, now we have all the others bytes:

```
13 20 00 10 02 00 00 00 D0 D2 0C C1 74 65 78 74 2F 78 2D 76 43 61 72 64 42 45 47 49 4E 3A 56 43 41 52 44 0D 0A 56 45 52 53 49 4F 4E 3A 32 2E 31
```

These bytes are a LLCP I PDU.

13 20 00 are DSAP (0x04), PTYPE (0x0C), SSAP (0x20) and Sequence (0x00).

So now we have only the Data Bytes.

```
10 02 00 00 00 D0 D2 0C C1 74 65 78 74 2F 78 2D 76 43 61 72 64 42 45 47 49 4E 3A 56 43 41 52 44 0D 0A 56 45 52 53 49 4F 4E 3A 32 2E 31 0D 0A 4E 3A 3B
```

We can easily understand that NDEF start at D2 (D2 is the flags, 0C the type length, ...)

So the question is here, what are the first bytes of these DATA?

```
10 02 00 00 00 D0
```

It's like an initialization, and I think 10 is version number, and the D0 is the length.
But from what documentation this initialization come from? I havn't found informations in any NFC Forum documentation.

[image: There is the comunication]

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, after some hours of google, I found the answer at my question.

When a NDEF message is transmit over a LLC protocol, there is a SNEP layer.

So the SNEP header is : Version - Put - Length (on 4 bytes)

In my case, version 1.0 (0x10), Put (0x02), and length D0 (0x00 0x00 0x00 0xD0).